# How to implement Traefik non-docker multiple domain forwarding

Tags: traefik, multiple-domains

I'd like to be able to use Traefik to forward traffic for a domain with subfolders to a docker container on a diff hosts. Also, I'd like to be able to use multiple separate domains.

I'm unable to find instructions or a guide to do that exactly. Can anyone give me pointers please?

This is what I have so far.

```
### traefik.toml

defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[api]
entryPoint = "traefik"
dashboard = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    ]
  [entryPoints.traefik]
  address = ":8080"
  [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
  users = ["admin:{SHA}123="]

[acme]
email = "123@123.com"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
onHostRule = false
acmeLogging = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.123.it"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.123.co.uk"


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "{{ DOMAIN }}"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[file]

[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
    url = "http://192.168.0.1:8585/"

  [backends.backend2]
    [backends.backend2.servers.server2]
    url = "http://192.168.0.1:8383/"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.graf]
    rule = "Host:123.it"

  [frontends.frontend2]
  backend = "backend2"
    [frontends.frontend2.routes.graf]
    rule = "Host:123.co.uk; PathPrefix: /app"
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. Could you give more details? and a diagram or something more specific about your goal.

Comment: OK, so I have a Linux box which is running a Traefik container which is already successfully serving a postfix email server and other things to subdomain.domain.tld and all with a working wildcard SSL from LetsEncrypt.


Now, I want to be able to forward/redirect from the same Traefik box to a different Linux box running some other docker containers. Stuff like SABnzbd and plex etc. If It's possible, I'd like to do this with a completely different domain.tld and SSL, but not mission critical at this stage.

Comment: SABnzbd and plex etc were all setup using Nginx into subfolders, so I'd like to mirror that too if it's possible